# Why am I getting the right shape, but wrong scaling on a very simple Fourier series toy example to reproduce the math?

Tags: r, image-processing, signal-processing, fft

It's done in R but it doesn't really matter: it follows practically verbatim the Wikipedia formulas, but something is off, and the final plot is as expected, but with totally different y values.

So the function to work on is standard Gaussian. I understand there is no periodicity, so right there it is not a good candidate for Fourier series, but this does not seem like a plausible explanation.

So here is the code and math followed:

> From [the Wikipedia entry on Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Definition):
>
> Consider a real-valued function, s(x), that is integrable on an interval of length P, which will be the period of the Fourier series.
>
> Integer n, used as an index, is also the number of cycles of the n-th harmonic in interval P.

[image]

[image]

with

[image]

```
# The function to decompose into a Fourier series:
 
x <- seq(-pi, pi, length.out=10000)
func <- dnorm(x)
plot(func, type='l', lwd=3, xlab='', ylab='' , main='Function to Decompose into a Fourier series')

# Obtaining the coefficients:

P <- length(x)
cosines <-rep(0,P) # Empty vector
for (n in 1:P){
  cosines[n] <- 2/P * sum(func * cos(2*pi/P * n * x))
}
sines <-rep(0,P)
for (n in 1:P){
  sines[n] <- 2/P * sum(func * sin(2*pi/P * n * x))
}
azero <- 2/P * sum(func)

# Reconstructing the function from the Fourier series:

mat <- matrix(0,2*P,P) # Empty 2P x P matrix to collect contribution for each harmonic value.
for(i in 1:P){
  mat[i,] <- cosines[i] * cos(2*pi/P * i * x)         # Multiplying each cosine harmonic basis component by its coefficient found above.
  mat[i+P,] <- sines[i] * sin(2*pi/P * i * x)         # Same for sine components.
}
inv.joseph <- rep(azero/2, P) + colSums(mat)
plot(inv.joseph, type='l', lwd=3, xlab='', ylab='', main='Inverse Fourier')
```

Answer (score 1):

I forgot the dx to discretize the integral:

###### The function:

```
dx <- 0.001
lim <- pi
x <- seq(-1*lim,1*lim,dx)
P <- max(x) - min(x)
func <- dnorm(x)
plot(func,type='l', lwd=3, xlab='', ylab='', main='Function to Decompose into a Fourier series')
```

[image]

###### Number of harmonic cosines and sines:

N <- 1:2000

###### Coefficients:

```
cosines <-rep(0,length(N)) # Empty vector
for (n in seq(along=N)){
  cosines[n] <- 2/P * sum(func * cos(2*pi/P * n * x)) * dx
}

sines <-rep(0,length(N))
for (n in seq(along=N)){
  sines[n] <- 2/P * sum(func * sin(2*pi/P * n * x)) * dx
}

azero <- 2/P * sum(func * dx)
```

###### Recreating the function (inverse Fourier):

```
mat <- matrix(0,2*length(N),length(x)) # Empty 2P x P matrix to collect contribution for each harmonic value.
for(i in seq(along=N)){
  mat[i,]   <- cosines[i] * cos(2*pi/P * i * x)         # Multiplying each cosine harmonic basis component by its coefficient found above.
  mat[i+length(N),] <- sines[i] * sin(2*pi/P * i * x)   # Same for sine components.
}
inv.joseph <- rep(azero/2, length(x)) + colSums(mat)
plot(inv.joseph, type='l', lwd=3, xlab='', ylab='', main='Inverse Fourier')
```

[image]